# External information on Solr's learning to rank plugin

Tags: machine-learning, solr, lucene

I have been using the [learning to rank plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Learning+To+Rank) for Solr created by Bloomberg and I totally recommend it. It is a fantastic work.

I have a question regarding the use of EFI. Let's say that I have the popularity of my documents (document hits) in an external SQL database instead of saving it in the index.

Can I use this information as a feature? How?